# How to disable elements while fetching data with react-query?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-query

My application is using `React Hook Form` and `React-Query` to fetch a character from an api by `id`. That `id` can either be the user's input or randomly generated.

When a user makes their first query, I want to disable the `input`, `fetch` button, and `random` button while fetching. I also want the `fetch` button and `random` button to be disabled if the character corresponding to the number in the `input` field is currently loaded, for any queries made afterwards.

My attempt implements React Hooks Form's `formState.isSubmitting` and `formState.isDirty`, but the input and buttons are not being disabled.

Please let me know how to implement the expected behavior.

[image: Edit 66774791/how-to-disable-elements-while-fetching-data-with-react-hook-form]

Comment: Just a quick note that you may have a mistake here: `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleRickAndMortyFetch)}>` that is actually calling the function. It should be `<form onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(handleRickAndMortyFetch)}>`

Comment: @Yuan-HaoChiang It's actually correct. Check out the first example from `https://react-hook-form.com/get-started`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to disable the input, fetch button, and random button while fetching.

Since you rely on `react-query` to fetch the data, you need to reference `isLoading` state to render the UI accordingly, every time the user submits the form, update `idQuery` to trigger the fetching again. Because you're fetching by ID, you should use [array keys](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-keys#array-keys) instead of string key.

Here is a minimal example to demonstrate what I mean:

```js
const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
const [idQuery, setIdQuery] = useState(0);
const handleRickAndMortyFetch = () => {
  return axios(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/${idQuery}`)
    .then((res) => res.data);
};
const { isLoading, data, error } = useQuery(
  ["rickandmorty", idQuery],
  handleRickAndMortyFetch
);
const disable = isLoading;
const onSubmit = (formData) => {
  setIdQuery(formData.rickAndMortyId);
};

return (
  <>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input name="rickAndMortyId" ref={register} disabled={disable} />
      <button type="submit" disabled={disable}>
        Search Character
      </button>
    </form>
    <RickAndMortyInfo data={data} />
  </>
);
```

> I also want the fetch button and random button to be disabled if the character corresponding to the number in the input field is currently loaded

This can be easily accomplished in `react-hook-form`, you just need to listen to the value from the input containing the ID by using `watch`, and compare it to the current `idQuery`:

```js
const { watch, ... } = useForm();
const formId = watch("rickAndMortyId");
const { isLoading, data, error } = useQuery(
  ["rickandmorty", idQuery],
  handleRickAndMortyFetch
);
const disable = isLoading || parseFloat(formId) === idQuery;
```

Also please note that you don't have to disable the search button for currently selected ID because `react-query` [caches](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/caching) your recently fetch results out-of-the-box. If you search the recent ID again, it skips the fetching process and gives you the cache results instead.

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66774791/how-to-disable-elements-while-fetching-data-with-react-hook-form]

Comment: Thank you very much, @NearHuscarl! I learned to reference `isLoading` state and use `array keys` when fetching by `id`. Also, to compare the input containing the id  to the current `idQuery`. Much appreciated!